# Can't commit to Bit Bucket through Xcode?

Tags: xcode, bitbucket, commit, checkout

I usually commit my project to Bit bucket through Xcode but now the option to commit is greyed out for some reason.

My username and password are correct for bit bucket as Well.

Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?!

Comment: Have you made any changes?

Comment: Cant post a screen shot because i don't have enough reputation. But what i can tell you is that all the buttons under the source control menu are greyed out except "Check out.."

Comment: Have you tried Checking Out?

Comment: Have you accidentally deleted the .git folder?

Comment: PS you shod now be able to post images.